# How to create a correlation between Angularjs and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

That is my question, how can I create a correlation between those frameworks ?

how do you communicate Angular with Node.

I am asking this because I have a Firebase project with Ionic/Angular, but I will not need Firebase anymore, all that stuff I am doing with Firebase should be migrated to Node.js with no discussion.

So, where should I start from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a project open source called mediacenter.js built with angular and node... 
In my opinion, it's good to see how they to organize and separate the front-end and backend. You should check it out at github.